# Switch statement with case constant comming as an argument doesnt compile

Tags: java

One of the roles for the switch statements is that they accept constants as arguments however observing the following code we can clearly notice a compilation error reported by the compiler at the marked line

```
public void testSwitch(final int y){
        final int x= 0;
        int tester = 9;
        switch(tester){
        case x:
            break;
        case y://compilation error here case constant must be constant expression
            break;
        }
    }
```

is this related to what is called  "Compile time" constants?

Comment: it is marked as final doesnt that make it a constant ?adding the following line would also make the compiler complain y=10;

Comment: I think the problem is that `y` can change values between calls, so in that sense it's not a 'constant expression'. You need something there that will not change, even between calls.

Comment: y is not a constant expression since you can call with whatever value of y you want, repeatedly.

Comment: It's not a _compile time_ constant.

Comment: @pvg damn, i was actually intrigued by this question until your link made me realize the value in the parameter was left off. now i just feel dumb. :(

Comment: "is this related to what is called 'Compile time' constants?" -- yes, yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

`y` parameter can have multiple values passed to the method call so it is not a constant. It could even be `0` value which would make it the same as `case x`